# How to set the state field to required? Add filter code and plug-ins not working

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, required-field

I need to have the state field in billing and shipping set as required.

I've tried to add custom code to the function.php, intalled various checkout plug-ins, changed the theme etc.but nothing is working. The field is still shown as optional. Any ideas?